# Summing values in one-line comma delimited file

Tags: file-io, language-agnostic, sum

***EDIT:*** Thanks all of you. Python solution worked lightning-fast :)

I have a file that looks like this:

```
132,658,165,3216,8,798,651
```

but it's **MUCH** larger (~ 600 kB). There are no newlines, except one at the end of file.

And now, I have to sum all values that are there. I expect the final result to be quite big, but if I'd sum it in C++, I possess a bignum library, so it shouldn't be a problem.

How should I do that, and in what language / program? C++, Python, Bash?

Comment: It's more a question of how / where this fits in the overall program. You don't take a dependency on a language just to do this.
Try doing it in the language that the surrounding code is written in, so if you want specific help, name the language.

Comment: I did it in C++, but I can't generate it again so I could sum it immediately.

Only thing I have is that text-file, so I guess programming language depends on people that'll reply here.

I only need it to be precise - no scientific notation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python

```
sum(map(int,open('file.dat').readline().split(',')))
```

Answer (score 6):

### Penguin Sed, "Awk"

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' tmp.txt | awk 'BEGIN {total=0} {total += $1} END {print total}'
```

### Assumptions

- Your file is tmp.txt (you can edit this obviously)
- Awk can handle numbers that large

Answer (score 1):

The language doesn't matter, so long as you have a bignum library.  A rough pseudo-code solution would be:

```
str = ""
sum = 0
while input
    get character from input
    if character is not ','
        append character to back of str
    else
        convert str to number
        add number to sum
        str = ""
output sum
```

Comment: Since the input isn't guaranteed to end in a comma, you'd also want to make sure that you convert and add str when the `while` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the numbers are smaller than (2**64)/600000 (which still has 14 digits), an 8 byte datatype like "long long" in C will be enough. The program is pretty straight-forward, use the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's expensive to treat that large input as a whole I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568968/does-any-one-know-of-a-faster-method-to-do-string-split/568983#568983) post. It explains how to write a generator for string splitting. It's in C# but it well suited for crunching through that kind of input.

If you are worried about the total sum to not fit in a integer (say 32-bit) you can just as easily implement a bignum your self, especially if you just use integer and addition. Just carry the bit-31 to next dword and keep adding.

If precision isn't important, just accumulate the result in a double. That should give you plenty of range.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid881E3E70CC37E480545A0C37C98BC8C208B06723.aspx?s=datatable#L12

A fast C# CSV parser.  I've seen it crunch though a few thousand 1MB files rather quickly, I have it running as part of a service that consumes about 6000 files a month.

No need to reinvent a fast wheel.

Answer (score -1):

python can handle the big integers.

Answer (score -1):

```
tr "," "\n" < file | any old script for summing
```

Ruby is convenient, since it automatically handles big numbers.  I can't remember of Awk does arbitrary precision arithmentic, but if so, you could use

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="," ; sum = 0 }
     {sum += $1 }
     END { print sum }' < file
```

Comment: this splits the line into fields, adds the first field to 0, ignores the other n-1 fields, spits out the first number and exits