# What is the Fastest way to split ':' seperated string into given number of chunks where result/record length is variable

Tags: c#

I have a large string accepted from TCP listner which is in following format

"1,7620257787,0123456789,99,0922337203,9223372036,32.5455,87,12.7857,1/1/2012,9223372036:1,7620257787,0123456789,99,0922337203,9223372036,32.5455,87,12.7857:2/1/2012,234234234:3,7620257787,01234343456789,99,0922337203,9223372036,32.5455,87,12.7857,1/1/2012,9223372036:34,76202343457787,012434343456789,93339,34340922337203,9223372036,32.5455,87,12.7857,1/1/2012,9223372036"

You can see that this is a : seperated string which contains Records which are comma seperated fields.

I am looking for the best (fastest) way that split the string in given number of chunks and take care that one chunk should contain full record (string upto  ':')

or other way of saying , there should not be any chunck which is not ending with :

e.g. 20 MB string to 4 chunks of 5 MB each with proper records (thus size of each chunk may not be exactly 5 MB but very near to it and total of all 4 chunks will be 20 MB)

I hope you can understand my question (sorry for the bad english)

I like the following link , but it does not take care of full record while spliting also don't know if that is the best and fastest way.

[Split String into smaller Strings by length variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008718/split-string-into-smaller-strings-by-length-variable)

Comment: Start with `string.Split()`. If you figure it really _is_ the bottleneck in your program, do a custom/optimized version (if at all possible). Other than that, this is question is most likely a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/568968/21567) one.

Comment: Did you already see this thread? "Does any one know of a faster method to do String.Split()?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568968/does-any-one-know-of-a-faster-method-to-do-string-split?lq=1

Comment: Please define 'large', Is your string just some kb or are you talking of Mb's or more?

Comment: what version of .NET are you using in this project?

Comment: @AntonSemenov I am using  .Net 4.0

Comment: Are your 'records' (the data between ":") of fixed length as it appears from yuor example?

Comment: @Steve , what I am showing is sample data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to divide the lenght of your data for the num of blocks required, then look backwards to search the last sep in the current block.

```
    private string[] splitToBlocks(string data, int numBlocks, char sep)
    {
        // We return an array of the request length
        if (numBlocks <= 1 || data.Length == 0)
        {
            return new string [] { data };
        }

        string[] result = new string[numBlocks];

        // The optimal size of each block
        int blockLen = (data.Length / numBlocks);

        int idx = 0; int pos = 0; int lastSepPos = blockLen;
        while (idx < numBlocks)
        {
            // Search backwards for the first sep starting from the lastSepPos
            char c = data[lastSepPos];
            while (c != sep) { lastSepPos--; c = data[lastSepPos]; }

            // Get the block data in the result array
            result[idx] = data.Substring(pos, (lastSepPos + 1) - pos);

            // Reposition for then next block
            idx++;
            pos = lastSepPos + 1;

            if(idx == numBlocks-1)
                lastSepPos = data.Length - 1;
            else
                lastSepPos = blockLen * (idx + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Please test it. I have not fully tested for fringe cases.

Comment: sorry for not providing full information , the strings are variable length strings.

Comment: Do you know an 'average' record size?

Comment: this looks exactly what I was looking, will try it tomorrow and compare the performance with the one given by Antone

Comment: @ImranRizvi, thanks for the added check. Another case to check is: what happens when you get a block without a separator inside? Admittedly, it's really improbable, but the code doesn't handle that situation.

Comment: Are you sure of your last change? if(numBlocks<=1 ....), if numBlocks == 1 I think you need all of the input data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how large a 'large string' is, but initially I would just try it with the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

Comment: I would not expect any problems with a string of size 4MB.

Comment: its seems to me what nowadays it's not a problem to hold "large" string in the memory even if its size 100mb

Comment: but when we talk about middleware servers, they are up and running , thus the size increases as time passes

Answer (score 1):

OK, I suggest you way with two steps:

1. Split string into chunks (see below)
2. Check chunks for completeness

Splitting string into chunks with help of linq (linq extension method taked from [Split a collection into `n` parts with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438188/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq) ):

```
string tcpstring = "chunk1 : chunck2 : chunk3: chunk4 : chunck5 : chunk6";
int numOfChunks = 4;

var chunks = (from string z in (tcpstring.Split(':').AsEnumerable()) select z).Split(numOfChunks);

List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (IEnumerable<string> chunk in chunks)
{
    result.Add(string.Join(":",chunk));                             
}

.......

static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var splits = from item in list
                     group item by i++ % parts into part
                     select part.AsEnumerable();
        return splits;
    }
}
```

Am I understand your aims clearly?

**[EDIT]**
In my opinion, In case of performance consideration, better way to use String.Split method for chunking

Comment: how can I pass number of chunks to create here?

Comment: I didnt understand your question clearly. For example, you recieved a string from TCP, it contains 10 chunks, but you want only three. You will take into account only first three or not?

Comment: suppose I received 10000 records (':' seperated), I want to create a chunk of 4 so each chunk will contain 2500 records, is it clear? Your code seems to create chunk of 10000

Comment: looks closer, I don't want enumerate : seperated values so I will need only IEnumerable<string> not IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>

Comment: I suppose that in most cases you desire to got array[N][X], where N is number of chunks and X is a number of records in every chunk. So you will get IEnumarable<string>. I made some modifications in my code, so you can clearly what i am talking about

Comment: I am able to get the IEnumerable<string> but I lost ':' separator now what I am getting in a chunk is long very long comma separated string.

Comment: see my answer again, the `result` list would contain what you are actually asking for

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to split on ":" (you can use the Split method).
Then you have to add ":" after splitting to each chunk that has been split.
(you can then split on "," for all the strings that have been split by ":".

Comment: I don't want to split by , . please read my question again , i've modified it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = yourstring.IndexOf(":");

string[] whatever = string.Substring(0,index);

yourstring = yourstring.Substring(index); //make a new string without the part you just cut out.
```

this is a general view example, all you need to do is establish an iteration that will run while the ":" character is encountered; cheers...

Comment: Are you sure about that string.Split(index) method? I don't know an overload with an int-argument.

Comment: sorry i ment string.Substring(0, index). where 0 is the start index and index is the point where it would stop.