# replace a character in string without using replace function in .NET

Tags: .net

Please can anyone advise me on how i can replace a particular character from a 2  mb string without using replace function in .NET

Thanks

Comment: You can use a `StringBuilder` or `unsafe` code. Be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: why don't you want to use replace function?

Comment: well, i knw replace is the best way to do it but i am after exploring more options/ways to do it

Comment: Because replace function creates a new string; string is immutable. @Gabe is right, use StringBuilder.

Comment: please refer this link , it has a good comparison between the 'replace' functions http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at some of the solutions discussed here:

[Memory Efficiency and Performance of String.Replace .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399798/memory-efficiency-and-performance-of-string-replace-net-framework)

It mentions the use of [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) and [`StringBuilder.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.replace.aspx)